# <mvc:default-servlet-handler /> blocking controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I have a jsp, which is submitting a form.

```
 <form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" action="j_spring_login"  method="post" class="login-form">
    <div class="login-inputTxt"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="User Name" required autofocus value=""/></div>
    <!--<small class="help-block" id="username-error-msg" style="display: none;"></small>-->
    <div class="login-inputTxt"><input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required value=""/></div>
    <!--<small class="help-block" id="password-error-msg" style="display: none;"></small>-->                        
    <div class="login-inputTxt">
        <select name="languagesel" id="languagesel" class="form-control" onChange="FnSelectLanguage(this.value)">
            <option value="english" selected> &nbsp;&nbsp; English</option>
            <option value="arabic">  &nbsp;&nbsp; Ø§ÙØ¹Ø±Ø¨ÙØ©</option>
        </select>

    </div>


    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="form-group text-center">
    <input type="submit" value="TEST">
    <!--   <a href="Javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default btn-block lngsigninhead" id="loginFormButton" onclick="FnLogin()">Sign In</a> -->
     </div>
    <span class="progress-bar text-right pull-right" id="progress-bar-login" style="display: none;"></span>
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>


    <!-- <div class="checkbox"><label style="font-size: 12px;  color: #e8c31c;  text-transform: initial;">Forgot Password?</label></div>    -->    
</form>
```

In my applicationContext I have

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.smart.city.*"></context:component-scan>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<!--  <mvc:annotation-driven />  -->
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="resources/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />

</bean>
```

I have a controller

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(value ="j_spring_login",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView maintainUserSession(HttpServletRequest request) {

        System.out.println("::::::::::: in maintainUserSession :::::::::" + request.getParameter("username"));
        System.out.println("::::::::::: in maintainUserSession :::::::::" + request.getParameter("password"));

    }
}
```

Here is my web.xml - servlet mapping

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My problem is if I use `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` my jsp is loading all static css, js & images, but it does not forward the request to my controller, and vice-versa

please assist

Comment: How is your servlet mapped, also you are using relative URLs which might be problematic. Your view-resolver is also using relative paths so might be problematic to.

Comment: Added servlet mapping from web.xml

Comment: For starters I would suggest using absolute URLs i.e. ` /j_spring_login` in both your form and controller. Also not sure if your view-resolver is setup correctly as that is using relative urls also. and `resources` sounds like a maven directory, JSPs should be somewhere inside the `WEB-INF` directory to prevent direct access.

Comment: changed /j_spring_login in controller to j_spring_login

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the prefix value to /resources/jsp. I hope the issue gets resolved